# Suppress warnings with loading tiff images in tensorflow doesn't seem to work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, warnings, tensorflow-datasets, suppress-warnings

I keep getting the following warning when using [tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/experimental/image/decode_tiff). I find that it works fine but keeps giving these warnings, which I want to suppress.

`TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, ASCII value for tag "DateTime" contains null byte in value; value incorrectly truncated during reading due to implementation limitations.`

I am using it as follows:

```
string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(string) # this line produces warning
```

If I try to suppress the warning using `warning`, it doesn't seem to work? It doesn't give me an error, but it doesn't do anything.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='ASCII value for tag "DateTime" contains null byte in value; value incorrectly truncated during reading due to implementation limitations')
```

How can I suppress this warning, or alternatively address the issue that produces the warning?

Comment: there is standard module `warnings` and you should find in Google many examples how to use it.

Comment: I did try it. It doesn't seem to work in this case, but perhaps I am using it incorrectly. I have updated my question to include it.

Comment: This does not work for me when I work with openslide and try to open a TIFF file to read_region. It's overflowing vscode ipynb memory and the kernel eventually crashes. I need to disable it but there's nothing working to suppress this warning from being printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to supress all warning then you can use

```
  warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

If want to supress some mesage then you have to use `message=...` with  beginning of message or with `.*` at the beginning

```
  warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message=".*ASCII value for tag")
```

---

Minimal example:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message=".*ASCII value for tag")

# some tests - it should be supressed by `filterwarnings()`
warnings.warn('TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, ASCII value for tag "DateTime" contains null byte in value; value incorrectly truncated during reading due to implementation limitations.')

print("Hello World")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have a follow up question. Can I use the same format to specify/suppress multiple warnings? My understanding is that I would copy the minimal example for each of the warnings. Also what is the difference between `filterwarnings` and `warn`? I tried to filter another warning `PNG warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile` using `message=.*known incorrect sRGB profile` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `warn` generate warning. I used it to show that `filterwarnings` is working. If you want to filter all warning then you use `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")`. All this works only if message was generated by `warn()` and `filterwarnings()`  was used before `warn`. If you use `filterwarnings` after `warn` then it can't stop it. If you have warning in imported module then you have to use fiter before import. And some warning can be normal `print()` and then you can't stop it.